# Iterate through nested array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I'm trying to iterate through a nested array object like below. What is the best way to access each of the object elements within the nested arrays.

```
{
    "titleId": "111G",
    "aNumber": "1212",
    "data": [{
            "id": "6657",
            "name": "test name",
            "city": "LA",
            "state": "CA",
            "comment": "comment 1",
            "dates": [{
                    "startDate": "01/17/2020",
                    "endDate": "01/22/2020"
                },
                {
                    "startDate": "01/24/2020",
                    "endDate": "01/30/2020"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "abc",
            "city": "NJ",
            "state": "NY",
            "comment": "comment 2",
            "dates": [{
                    "startDate": "01/17/2020",
                    "endDate": "01/22/2020"
                },
                {
                    "startDate": "01/24/2020",
                    "endDate": "01/30/2020"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to access each of the elements in data and the dates array as well

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand the question correctly you want to iterate over the dates array inside of each item in the data item, this is how I would do it in js

```
var date = JSON.parse(res.data)

date.forEach(element => {
    var items =  element.dates
    items.forEach(current => {
        //do whatever 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const info = {
    "titleId": "111G",
    "aNumber": "1212",
    "data": [{
            "id": "6657",
            "name": "test name",
            "city": "LA",
            "state": "CA",
            "comment": "comment 1",
            "dates": [{
                    "startDate": "01/17/2020",
                    "endDate": "01/22/2020"
                },
                {
                    "startDate": "01/24/2020",
                    "endDate": "01/30/2020"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "abc",
            "city": "NJ",
            "state": "NY",
            "comment": "comment 2",
            "dates": [{
                    "startDate": "01/17/2020",
                    "endDate": "01/22/2020"
                },
                {
                    "startDate": "01/24/2020",
                    "endDate": "01/30/2020"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
info.data.forEach(city => city.dates.forEach(cityDate => console.log(cityDate.startDate)))
```